# Create multiple arrays from existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I am stuck at one place where I have 3 arrays as below:

```
$c = array("red","green","blue");
$s = array("12","13","14");
$l = array("3","4","5");
```

Based on this array I need arrays like:

```
$one = array("red", "12", "3");
$two = array("red", "12", "4");
$three = array("red", "12", "5");
$three = array("red", "13", "3");
...........
```

Same I need to create array which include all combinations of above 3 arrays.

I have tried to create by looping through all, but can anyone tell me a better solution or existing php function for this.

Comment: The "looping through all" solution should only be about 4 lines of code, why are you looking for something "better"?

Comment: Thanks @deceze, it is better solution than I have made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a helper class for that:

https://github.com/noptic/co3/blob/master/src/daliaIT/co3/util/generator/ArrayGenerator.php

The package is no longer mantained but you can remove the 'IInject' interface and the "inject" method and use it as a standalone class.

The class can be iterated with foreach without creating all the combinations in memory.

If you need a "real" array call the "toArray" method